# how to store data for access on android phone

Tags: android, sql, storage, database-server

I am creating an application that stores details for the user, but as there may be many different users over a wide area.

I am just wondering what would be the best way to store this information so that it can be easily obtained and changed by the application?

Answer (score 1):

You must googling before asking question here. There are lot of examples for Storing the Data.

Author [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) provides you a best way for storing the data in Database. Please refer this.